# Installing Jedi JCL JVCL in Delphi XE2 Starter

Tags: delphi

Has anyone managed to install Jedi JCL JVCL in Delphi XE2 Starter on Windows 8.1 64 bit?

I have tried a number of the installers but all to no avail.

I only recently jumped back in to Delphi after a number of years away from programming and am very rusty to say the least.

What installer would you recommend?.

Comment: I must  add that I have Delphi 6 starter/personal installed on the same machine and don't know if that will affect the install.

Comment: After much deliberation and searching, I found a version of the binary installers that works.


Here are the links below.                   


JCL Binary installer for Delphi XE2 http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/28775

JVCL Binary installer for Delphi XE2  http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/28776

Comment: Problem solved and it worked perfectly, so anyone with the same configuration try this install.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Great that you solved the problem on your own. It's better to answer your own question instead of providing the solution in the comments. So, write an answer to this question, accept it and gain reputation from it in the future.

Answer (score 3):

After much deliberation and searching, I found a version of the binary installers that works.

Here are the links below.

JCL Binary installer for Delphi XE2  cc.embarcadero.com/Item/28775

JVCL Binary installer for Delphi XE2 cc.embarcadero.com/item/28776

Problem solved and it worked perfectly, so anyone with the same configuration try this install